# Get List of Nouns & Adjectives from WordNet

Tags: c#, mysql, wordnet

I am pretty new to Wordnet and so finding it a little confusing to be honest. Just wondering how I am able to generate a full list of nouns and a full list of adjectives from the Wordnet database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the MySQL version of Wordnet 3.0 you can use the following query:

select lemma from words left join senses on words.wordid = senses.wordid left join synsets on senses.synsetid = synsets.synsetid where pos = 'n'

And replace 'n' with 'a' for the adjectives.

Steve