# Get a large collection of Nouns from WordNet

Tags: java, wordnet

I want to retrieve a list of around 5000 nouns from WordNet randomly.I came across [JAWS(Java API for WordNet Searching)](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter). But I couldnt't find a efficient way out to do so. Is it even possible with JAWS?

I also saw this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108757/get-list-of-nouns-adjectives-from-wordnet). But this uses SQL version. I want to get the results through an API.

How can I proceed further on the problem? Please help.

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or something you need to do regularly and automatically? (Also, do you mean 5000 synsets, or 5000 words?)

Comment: Yes Darren. This is a one time task. I want to get 5000 synsets of Nouns at random.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RiTa (http://www.rednoise.org/rita/wordnet/documentation/) for this. They have a

> getRandomWords(pos, count)

method: 
http://www.rednoise.org/rita/wordnet/documentation/riwordnet_method_getrandomwords.htm

Just use it like

```
String[] randomNouns =  wordnet.getRandomWords("n", 5000);
```